# Dual map and adjoint map

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, symmetric-matrices

Let $X,Y$ be vector space over $\mathbb C$

Let $B ,B_1$ be an orthonormal basis of $X,Y$ respectively 
And $B_1^*,B_2^*$ be basis of dual space $X^*,Y^*$
$$\begin{array}{c} Y & \xrightarrow{A^\dagger} & X \\ I_Y \downarrow ~~~~~&& ~~~~\downarrow I_X \\ Y^* & \xrightarrow{A^*} & X^* \end{array}$$
Such that the diagram commutes
Now, matrix of dual map is Transpose of matrix of $A$.
But matrix of adjoint matrix is conjugate transpose .

Could someone explain me why this happens. Why one matrix is transpose and another is conjugate transpose?In such cases how diagram commutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ have inner product $\langle -, - \rangle: X \times X \to \mathbb{C}$. I will suppose that the inner product is antilinear in its first argument and linear in its second argument, so $\langle \lambda x_1, \mu x_2 \rangle = \overline{\lambda} \mu \langle x_1, x_2 \rangle$.

Then the map $\phi_X: X \to X^*$ given by $x \mapsto \langle x, - \rangle$ cannot be represented by a matrix as it is not a linear map, which we can see by looking at $(\lambda x) \mapsto \langle \lambda x, - \rangle = \overline{\lambda} \langle x, - \rangle$. If $\phi_X(x) = f$, then $\phi_x(\lambda f) = \overline{\lambda} \phi_x(f)$.

If you did want to write down a "matrix" for $\phi_X$, then you would need to be sure to complex-conjugate all of the inputs before sending them through the matrix. (You should work out why this fixes the problem!). It also restores the commutativity of the diagram.

Comment: I will work it out and ask you if i have any doubts. Thank you